# Strong Induction Based Proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> Consider the following inductive definition of a good sequence of 0's
>   and 1's.
>
> Foundation: The empty sequence is a good sequence.
>
> Constructor: If s and t are good sequences, then so are 0s1t and 1s0t.
>
> Use strong structural induction to show that every good sequence
>   consists of an equal number of 0's and 1's. Make sure to indicate what
>   P(n) is (i.e., the predicate you are proving holds true for all
>   natural number n).

I was given this question on a discrete mathematics homework assignment ( so no direct solutions please) but I would like some guidance or confirmation on my current way of thinking about the problem.

I am currently thinking about evaluating each P(n) as any sequence containing n 0's, then showing these are 'good' sequences iff the number of 1's are equal to n also.  Is this an appropriate way to approach the problem or is there an easier way to do this

Comment: I don't think the stronger statement that "all sequences with an equal number of $1$'s and $0$'s are good sequences and all good sequences have an equal number of $1$'s and $0$'s" is necessary.  Only prove one direction.  The problem statement implies that if $a$ is a good sequence, then it is of the form $1s0t$ or $0s1t$ where $s$ and $t$ are also good sequences.  Approaching via strong induction works well here.  Remember that for strong induction (and for induction in general), you try to take what you are unsure about and break it into smaller pieces that you do know something about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider finite sequences of $-1$ and $1$ instead. Each such sequence ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$, $n\geq0$, has  a *weight* $w({\bf x}):=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\in{\mathbb Z}$. It is obvious from the givens that all good sequences have weight $0$.

Answer (score 0):

It should also have been stated in the def'n that good sequences are ONLY those finite binary sequences that are obtained from the empty sequence by recursive applications of the "constructor". This provides a clue: Suppose $n$ is an even non-negative integer, and every good sequence of length $\leq n$ is of even length and has an equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s.

Then (1) Can there exist a sequence of length $n+1$? and (2) How do we obtain a sequence of length $n+2$?